# Setting value in row with value from another row in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2017. I need help with setting a value in a row with a value from a different row in the same table based on matching criteria.

Looking at the results screenshot below, the highlighted '0' in "TaskHeaderKey" should be set to the "TaskKey" value of '332807. This should happen when the value in "TaskNumber" *without* a '-' matches the value *before* the '-' in all other rows. As you can see, I am only able to get part of this done by setting the "TaskHeaderKey" to the "TaskKey" where "TaskNumber" does not contain a '-'.

[image: Results]

This is the code I have so far:

```
UPDATE tt1
SET tt1.TaskHeaderKey = tt2.TaskKey
FROM Task tt1
  INNER JOIN Task tt2 ON tt1.TaskKey = tt2.TaskKey
  INNER JOIN Project pj ON tt1.ProjectKey = pj.ProjectKey
WHERE pj.IntelTIProject = 1 AND pj.ProjectOpen = 1
AND (IIf(charindex('-', tt1.TaskNumber) = 0, tt1.TaskNumber, Left(tt1.TaskNumber, charindex('-', tt1.TaskNumber) - 1)) = tt2.TaskNumber)
AND ISNUMERIC(Left(tt2.TaskNumber, 1)) = 1
AND tt1.ProjectKey = tt2.ProjectKey
```

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT**
Based on the accepted answer, this is what I used:

```
UPDATE td1
SET td1.TaskHeaderKey = tdx.TaskKey
FROM
Task td1
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT top (1)
            td2.TaskKey
        FROM
            Task td2
            INNER JOIN Project pj ON td2.ProjectKey = pj.ProjectKey
        WHERE
            td1.ProjectKey = td2.ProjectKey
            AND pj.IntelTIProject = 1
            AND pj.ProjectOpen = 1
            AND td1.TaskNumber LIKE td2.TaskNumber + '%'
            AND td2.TaskNumber NOT LIKE '%-%'
            AND ISNUMERIC(Left(td2.TaskNumber, 1)) = 1
        ) tdx
WHERE 
td1.taskheaderkey = 0;
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result instead of images thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it will give you the results you're looking for.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #TestData; END;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    taskkey INT NOT NULL,
    tasknumber VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    taskheaderkey INT NOT NULL,
    productkey INT NOT NULL
    );
INSERT #TestData (taskkey, tasknumber, taskheaderkey, productkey) VALUES
    (332807, '091', 332807, 2710),
    (405311, '091-0099', 0, 2710);


--================================================

UPDATE td1 SET 
    td1.taskheaderkey = tdx.taskkey
FROM
    #TestData td1
    CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT top (1)
                td2.taskkey
            FROM
                #TestData td2
            WHERE 
                td1.productkey = td2.productkey
                AND td1.tasknumber LIKE td2.tasknumber + '%'
                AND td2.tasknumber NOT LIKE '%-%'
            ) tdx
WHERE 
    td1.taskheaderkey = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. I would have not been able to solve this without your help.